# Get the Value of Input box and put this in a "let" variable

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried a to make a Input box and get the Value of this. I've made it, that the value show with an alert.

My HTML Code where I need help is:

```js
let Ausgang_popup = "[]";
```

```html
<div id="steuerung">
  <label for="Start">Startpunkt:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Start" id="Start" placeholder="Ausgangskoordinaten" required>
  <button onclick="Ausgang_popup = document.getElementById('Start').value;alert([Ausgang_popup])">Ausgang Übernehmen</button>
</div>
```

But the Value isn't im my let "Ausgang_popup". How can I get the value into the variable?
Later I have to work with this Value.

I've tried to do this:

```js
let Ausgang_popup = "[]";
```

```html
<div id="steuerung">
  <label for="Start">Startpunkt:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Start" id="Start" placeholder="Ausgangskoordinaten" required>
  <button onclick="Ausgang_popup = document.getElementById('Start').value;alert([Ausgang_popup]); let Ausgang_popup = ([Ausgang_popup])">Ausgang Übernehmen</button>
</div>
```

But it did not work.

My Complete Code - with help from the answears is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

function ausgang_popup(){
          const input = document.getElementById('start').value;
          alert(input);
          var Ausgang_popup = (input)
        } 
    
       
    
        
        Startpunkt:
    
            
            Ausgang Übernehmen

```css
#steuerung {
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
        width:25%;
        background-color: gray;
        clear: both;
      }
  
    #mapid {
      height: 600px;
      width: 900px;
      margin-left: 25%;
      margin-right: 25%;
      text-align: center;
      border: 5px solid #020202;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>


   <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

       
    <script>
        function ausgang_popup(){
          const input = document.getElementById('start').value;
          alert(input);
          var Ausgang_popup = (input)
        } 
    </script>
       
    <div id="steuerung">
        
        <label for="Start">Startpunkt:</label>
    
            <input type="text" name="Start" id="start" placeholder="Ausgangskoordinaten" required>
            <button onclick= "ausgang_popup()">Ausgang Übernehmen</button>
    </div>


    <div id="mapid">

<script>

    let mymap = L.map("mapid").setView([48.770654, 9.182647], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', 
{
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: "pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9uYXNsZW8yNTEwIiwiYSI6ImNrbGZkeGc1NDE5Y2wydm1qYWZwdGJkdmUifQ.EEyCsKPPrbW-WloF-dM8WQ"
}).addTo(mymap);
//create map


let popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("Koordinaten: " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
//clicked on map
</script>

<script>
    let marker = L.marker([input]).addTo(mymap);
    //blue marker
</script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

JonasLeo2510

Comment: There's a few things that could be improved. There is no closing script tag, and `Ausgang_popup` is being redeclared.

Comment: *"the value show with an alert [...] But the Value isn't im my let "Ausgang_popup""* - But that variable is exactly what you're showing in your `alert`.  So that would pretty strongly confirm that you are indeed setting a value to that variable.  In what way are you observing otherwise?  What's the actual problem which led to the attempt in your second example?  Perhaps you could update the question to include a complete runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to create a function in your `script` tags and then call that function in your `onclick`:

```html
<script>
    function ausgang_popup(){
      const input = document.getElementById('start').value;
      alert(input);
    } 
</script>
   
<div id="steuerung">
    
    <label for="Start">Startpunkt:</label>

        <input type="text" name="Start" id="start" placeholder="Ausgangskoordinaten" required>
        <button onclick= "ausgang_popup()">Ausgang Übernehmen</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answear! I've addet a " var Ausgang_popup = (input)" under the "alert(input)" to get the input for the Variable. But I havn't got it. Have I made sth false?

Comment: Okay I had to modify this a bit but I think/hope this will get you what you want! `<script>
   let ausgang_popup = '';
    function ausgang(){
      const input = document.getElementById('start').value;
      alert(input);
      ausgang_popup = input;
    } 
</script>`

Comment: I made a codepen if it's easier for you to see whats going on: https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/JjbpMge

Comment: Also it is best practice not to capitalize the first letter of a variable, hence `let ausgang_popup`

Comment: If this helps you out please upvote my answer, thanks!

Comment: I dont't know why, but now the input is not displayed as an alert :(

My Code:
 <script>    
  let ausgang_popup = '';
            function ausgang(){       
                const input = document.getElementById('start').value;      
                alert(input);      
                ausgang_popup = input;
            } 
            </script>

            
        
        <label for="Start">Startpunkt:</label>
    
 <input type="text" name="Start" id="start" placeholder="Ausgangskoordinaten" required>
            <button onclick= "ausgang_popup()">Ausgang Übernehmen</button>

Comment: Oh I changed the function name to `ausgang()` to cut down on confusion and in the onclick you still have it as `ausgang_popup()`. Sorry about that

Comment: Ahh Thank You! It's the first time, I use a function so sorry, i havn't seen it